# A primary key's issue in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, create-table

While creating a table it automatically sets the int type column primary key. I don't know why.

```
create table CongViec
(
    ID_VT int not null,
    TenVT text,
    loaiVT text,
    donvt text,
    tinhtrang text, 
    xuatxu text, 
    soluongton int,
    minhhoa text,
    ghichu text,
    primary key (ID_VT)
) engine=csv
```

> Too many keys specified; max 0 keys allowed

Comment: `engine=csv` -- are your sure about engine?

Comment: @sectus yes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/csv-storage-engine.html

Comment: AKAIK, `PRIMARY KEY` also creates `INDEX` on the specified column. And `CSV` engine does not support `INDEX`ing. There are some limitations on `CSV` engine. [CSV Engine Limitations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/se-csv-limitations.html)

Comment: There is/was no question in this post. Also this post is extremely unclear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS Please use standard spelling & punctuation. Please indent code reasonably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove engine=csv thats it

```
create table CongViec(
ID_VT int not null,
TenVT text,
loaiVT text,
donvt text,
tinhtrang text, 
xuatxu text, 
soluongton int,
inhhoa text,
ghichu text,
primary key (ID_VT)
);
```

[See here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a67c7)

Answer (score 2):

The CSV engine does not support indexes, including primary keys.

More information [in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/se-csv-limitations.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use engine=InnoDB instead of engine=csv, there is no csv engine in MySQL.